# Difference between cURL headers

Tags: php, curl, paypal, libcurl

What is difference between below headers sent by cURL?

```
$header="POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .="Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .="Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
```

And

```
$header = array ('POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1', 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Host: www.paypal.com', 'Connection: close');
```

Used for

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
```

Can I use both methods for setting up headers for cURL?Thanks

Comment: The docs (http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) do not mention the first solution, I would stick with the second solution.

Comment: You are right, I use the second solution too but I got an email from PayPal for upgrading to HTTP 1.1 and they mentioned the first solution. The header must be either object or an array. Can use the second solution keeping in mind the header values in first solution?

Comment: It's PayPal, ignore everything they have to say about code. Their site is painfully slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both solutions are wrong although the second is less wrong.

Both include the POST line which is the request line and not actually a header by definition. Thus, including that in the header option will create a bad request. (but yes, it may still work)